# How to use Embedding() with 3D tensor in Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras, lstm, word-embedding

I have a list of stock price sequences with 20 timesteps each. That's a 2D array of shape (total_seq, 20). I can reshape it into (total_seq, 20, 1) for concatenation to other features.

I also have news title with 10 words for each timestep. So I have 3D array of shape (total_seq, 20, 10) of the news' tokens from `Tokenizer.texts_to_sequences()` and `sequence.pad_sequences()`.

I want to concatenate the news embedding to the stock price and make predictions.

> My idea is that the news embedding should return tensor of shape
>   (total_seq, 20, embed_size) so that I can concatenate it with the
>   stock price of shape (total_seq, 20, 1) then connect it to LSTM layers.
>
> To do that, I should convert news embedding of shape (total_seq, 20, 10) to 
>   (total_seq, 20, 10, embed_size) by using Embedding() function.
>
> But in Keras, the Embedding() function takes a 2D tensor instead of 3D tensor. How do I get around with this problem?

Assume that Embedding() accepts 3D tensor, then after I get 4D tensor as output, I would remove the 3rd dimension by using LSTM to return last word's embedding only, so output of shape (total_seq, 20, 10, embed_size) would be converted to (total_seq, 20, embed_size)

> But I would encounter another problem again, LSTM accepts 3D tensor not 4D so
>
> How do I get around with Embedding and LSTM not accepting my inputs?

Answer (score 0):

one workaround is to get all time stamps and news feature together

```
timesstaps feature = tensor(total_seq, 20)
news_feature = tensor(total_seq, 20, 10)
news_feature_reshaped = reshape(news_feature, (total_seq, 200))
final_features = concat([timestamps_feature, news_fature_reshaped], axis=1)
```

Comment: News are int token values they should be passed to Embedding first.

Comment: And 20 is the sequence length, the final sequence length should not be changed.

Comment: here's sequence length is preserved; reshaping and concatenating not gonna make any changes, it also addresses the goal of using embedding.

Comment: final_features will have shape (total_seq, 220) right?

Comment: If that is the case, then LSTM would not work on this 2D tensor. Because LSTM that I would want to connect accepts 3D tensor.

Comment: And the output of the LSTM given that `return_sequences=True` would be `(total_seq, 220)` which is not what I wanted, I want the output to be `(total_seq, 20)` so that I can treat this as price predictions.

Comment: Another caveat, you cannot concatenate 2 different types together. `news_feature_reshaped` would be an `int` tensor. And the `timestamps_feature` would be a `float` tensor. The `news_feature` is not an embedding tensor. It's a token tensor.

Comment: you can always convert the data types, that won't change results.

Comment: You didn't understand the problem. I want to pass news to the Embedding() function. Your approach doesn't seem to include Embedding into it at all. It seems like you assume that `news_feature` is already an embedding.

Comment: Please show me how to use Embedding function with this approach.

Comment: ohh! my bad! i missed that. this solution mayn't be optimal in that case then.